# AWS Waiter TasksStopped failed: taskId length should be one of

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

For some reason I am getting the following error:

**Waiter TasksStopped failed: taskId length should be one of [32,36]**

I really don't know what taskId is supposed to mean and aws documentation isn't helping. Does anyone know what is going wrong in this pipeline script?

```
    - step:
    name: Run DB migrations
    script:
    - >
      export BackendTaskArn=$(aws cloudformation list-stack-resources \
                          --stack-name=${DEXB_PRODUCTION_STACK} \
                          --output=text \
                          --query="StackResourceSummaries[?LogicalResourceId=='BackendECSTask'].PhysicalResourceId")
    - >
      SequelizeTask=$(aws ecs run-task --cluster=${DEXB_PRODUCTION_ECS_CLUSTER} --task-definition=${BackendTaskArn} \
                        --overrides='{"containerOverrides":[{"name":"NodeBackend","command":["./node_modules/.bin/sequelize","db:migrate"]}]}' \
                        --launch-type=EC2 --output=text --query='tasks[0].taskArn')
    - aws ecs wait tasks-stopped --cluster=${DEXB_PRODUCTION_ECS_CLUSTER} --tasks ${SequelizeTask}
```

Answer (score 3):

AWS introduced [a new ARN format](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/) for tasks, container instances, and services. This format now contains the cluster name, which might break scripts and applications that were counting on the ARN only containing the task resource ID.

```
# Previous format (taskId contains hyphens)
arn:aws:ecs:$region:$accountID:task/$taskId

# New format (taskI does not contain hyphens)
arn:aws:ecs:$region:$accountId:task/$clusterName/$taskId
```

Until March 31, 2021, it will be possible to opt-out of this change per-region, using https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?#/settings. In order to change the behavior for the whole account, you will need to use the Root IAM user.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I had a duplicate task running in the background. I went to the ECS clusters page and stopped the duplicate task. However this may be dangerous to do if you have used cloudformation to set up your tasks and services. Proceed cautiously if you're in the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

We were bit with this cryptic error message, and what it actually means is that the task_id you're sending to cloudformation script is invalid. Task ids must have a length of 32 or 36 chars.
In our case, an undocumented change in the way AWS sent back taskArn key value was causing us to grab the incorrect value, and sending an unrelated string as the task_id. AWS detected this and blew up. So double check the task_id string and you should be good.